# Append find result to txt file

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to concat `jpg` and `png` images with the use of ffmpeg. Before doing so, I am trying to append the file name and paths to a txt file. However, I am getting an error. The files have to follow the format `file '/media/test.jpg'` for appending to the txt file. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Print files:

```
find . \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' \) -print
```

Error when trying this:

```
find . \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' \) printf "file '%s'\n"  > mylist.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' \) -printf "file '%p'\n" >> mylist.txt
```